# angular resolve returns function instead of value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to refactor some code out of my controller and into the route's 'resolve' and am having trouble getting the correct return value from `resolve`. I think the problem is either due to my misunderstanding of js closures or the $q library in angular.

In the routing:

```
.when('/countries/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'country/country.html',
      controller: 'countryCtrl',
      resolve: {
        ActiveCountry: ['CountryData', '$q', '$route', function(CountryData, $q, $route) {
          var defer = $q.defer();
          CountryData($route.current.params.id).then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            defer.resolve(data);
          });
          return defer.promise;
        }]
      }
    })
```

The `console.log` in this block returns the correct JSON object from the api call. However, when it is passed into the controller, the controller returns the function from the `CountryData` service:

```
.controller('countryCtrl', [
  'CountryData',
  '$routeParams',
  '$scope',
  function (ActiveCountry, $routeParams, $scope) {
    var countryId = $routeParams.id;
    console.log(ActiveCountry);
    $scope.mapId = $routeParams.id.toLowerCase();
    $scope.country = ActiveCountry;
  }
]);
```

The value of the routing `console.log` is:
`Object {countryName: "Spain", currencyCode: "EUR", fipsCode: "SP", countryCode: "ES", isoNumeric: "724"…}`

but the controller console log is the function from my `CountryData` service:

```
function (countryId) {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      $http.get(COUNTRIES_PATH + '&country=' + countryId + API_AUTH, { cache: true }).success(function (data) {
        defer.resolve(data.geonames[0]);
      });
      return defer.promise;
    }
```

Why is the object from the routing not being passed into the controller correctly?

Also, why do I need to use `$q` in the router when it is already built into the `CountryData` service? Without using `$q` in the routing, it returns the function rather than the function's return value.

Comment: `why do I need to use $q in the router when it is already built into the CountryData service` You don't have to. Just make CountryData return promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put 'CountryData' and then ActiveCountry for your controller arguments.  So they do not match up.

It should be 'CountryData' and CountryData

```
controller('countryCtrl', [
  'CountryData',
  '$routeParams',
  '$scope',
  function (CountryData, $routeParams, $scope) {
    var countryId = $routeParams.id;
    console.log(ActiveCountry);
    $scope.mapId = $routeParams.id.toLowerCase();
    $scope.country = ActiveCountry;
  }
]);
```

Comment: nice catch! starred at this for a few hours

Answer (score 1):

Angular will automatically resolve any promises that are returned from functions on the resolve property.  So, your resolve property should look like this:

```
resolve: {
  ActiveCountry: ['CountryData', '$q', '$route', function(CountryData, $q, $route) {
    return CountryData($route.current.params.id);
  }
}
```

Before invoking your controller method `$routeProvider` will resole all promises that are passed as parameters to the controller.  For more information, see [$routeProvider.when()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider).

Comment: looks like maybe the problem is in my service? If I set the resolve to ```console.log(CountryData($route.current.params.id);``` it does not log the return value, but the function itself: ```Object {then: function, catch: function, finally: function}``` However, in Chrome console network I can see that the service is making the api call as it should.